# Unable to import module 'handler' aws lambda function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I keep getting this error and I don't know what is causing it.

I am having an API that based on a condition will post to another API, 
but I get this error in my wrapping API.

Here is the code ...

**handler.js**

```
'use strict';
const axios = require('axios');

module.exports.thumbnailWrapperAPI = (event, context, callback) => {


  const incomingData = JSON.parse(event.body);
  if(incomingData.source.includes('png') || incomingData.source.includes('jpg')){
    const newLocal = 'some endpoint...';
    // call image resizing API...
    axios.post(newLocal,{
      source: incomingData.source,
      target: incomingData.target,
      width: incomingData.width
    })
    .then(response => callback(null,response))
    .catch(error => callback(error))

  } else if(incomingData.source.includes('html')) {
    // handle HTML
  } else {
    //...
  };
};
```

**serverless.yaml**

```
service: thumbnailWrapperAPI 
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  region: eu-west-1

functions:
  thumbnailWrapperAPI:
    handler: handler.thumbnailWrapperAPI
    events:
      - http:
          path: generatethumbnail/
          method: post
          cors: true
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
Unable to import module 'handler': Error
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/handler.js:2:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

Comment: Post your full code. From where are you requiring `handler.js`? Show the full path of files. And also please post your whole error too.

Comment: This is the full code. The other files that I have are the serverless.yaml, which I will  post now and package,json and the package-lock.json

Comment: post your whole error. That would be helpful to dig.

Comment: @HardikShah Posted the error and serverless.yaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I solved it by removing my package.json then adding it again and installing  **NOT** as dev dependencies my packages and it worked.

Comment: removing _what_ from `package.json`? Adding _what_ again ?

Comment: @CodyBugstein Deleting the whole package.json file, adding the file again with npm init, fresh install of all modules I am dependant on but **not** as dev dependencies. This worked for me, hope that helps.

Comment: @CodyBugstein I am sure there are plenty of ways to do it, but this is the way I did it and it worked for me. If you came here to critisize my way and downvote the answer which worked best for me then atleast provide some expertise on why and what should be done to avoid this problem in the future.

Comment: I did provide a better solution in the comment, Your solution is ok but it may lead people to put everything in dependencies when some things should really stay in devDependencies.

Comment: @squeekyDave npm init (does that for serverless json) I have written lambda serverless in python. how should I get back my deleted package-lock.json ?

Comment: @ChaitanyaBapat I am not sure how a python project should work, this was a node project.

Answer (score 8):

The error message doesn't help too much, but I found out that this message is often caused by a lost npm package. If you test the lambda in the AWS console, you can see the specific details.

Comment: "If you test the lambda in the AWS console, you can see the specific details" This comment is golden. Couldn't find this help anywhere else. thanks @aarkerio

Answer (score 2):

You will also get this error when you require a module or file using a wrong path. In other words requiring a module/file that does not exist.

It could be a custom module or npm.

Please double check all your module import paths and see that they are accurate.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it turned out that I used both python and nodejs for my lambdas, but hadn't set the nodejs lambda function's runtime environment as nodejs. Previously, my **serverless.yml** looked similar to this:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.7
  stage: dev
  region: eu-west-1 
  profile: my-profile

functions:
  nodejs-func:
    handler: nodejs_func.handler
    events:
      - websocket:
          route: nodejs-func
  python-func:
    handler: python_func.handler
    events:
      - websocket:
          route: python-func
```

Simply give the runtime  environment for the nodejs lambda in order to solve this:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.7
  stage: dev
  region: eu-west-1 
  profile: my-profile

functions:
  nodejs-func:
    handler: nodejs_func.handler
    runtime: nodejs10.x # Provide the runtime environment for lambda func
    events:
      - websocket:
          route: nodejs-func
  python-func:
    handler: python_func.handler
    events:
      - websocket:
          route: python-func
```